# How to send email when from SPD 2013 workflow fails?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

How can we send email notification to admins if any designer workflow fails for any reason at any stage.

What is the workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new view and filter it with Workflow Status = "Failed"

Next create an Alert on that View. This way you will get notified when new items get added to the failed group.